# Can A Postgres Replication Publication And Subscription Exist On The Same Server

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have a request asking for a read only schema replica for a role in postgresql. After reading documentation and better understanding replication in postgresql, I'm trying to identify whether or not I can create the publisher and subscriber within the same database.

Any thoughts on the best approach without having a second server would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about install a VM and running there the second server?

Comment: Which type of replication? For physical/streaming replication the answer is no. For logical replication the answer is yes, but it has some quirks setting it up.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for wanting to have a replica? If it is on the same server (hardware), it is more efficient to grant read-only access to the schema in the (publisher) database.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. It has been helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked two different question.  Same database?  No.  Since Pub/Sub requires tables to have the same name (including schema) on both ends, you would be trying to replicate a table onto itself.  Using logical replication plugins other than the built-in one might get around this restriction.

Same server?  Yes.  You can replicate between two databases of the same instance (but see the note in the docs about some extra hoops you need to jump through) or between two instances on the same host. So whichever of those things you meant by "same server", yes, you can.

But it seems like an odd way to do this.  If the access is read only, why does it matter whether it is to a replica of the real data or to the real data itself?

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. My thought when reading the request was to provide read only access to the necessary tables. The request specifically coming down from well above my pay grade specifically asked for replication. I’ll present my thoughts echoing your question, and ask for some clarification as well.

Comment: Could you clarify about `some extra hoops you need to jump through`, since I couldn't find it in the documentation?
My query to create a subscription to the same postgres instance for a small table is executed without errors indefinitely.

Comment: Regarding the question of why it may be necessary - to isolate data within the boundaries of microservices. It is a common practice to cache data from another microservice, and this is essentially a reliable way of caching.
Although in reality, in my case, the answer lies in bureaucracy. There are provisions on the need to separate data by microservices and that each database should have its own account with rights only to this database. With different accounts, I can't do joins between tables in different databases, but I can replicate a table to another database.